# Como acessar registro próximo e anterior com C# utilizando Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, entity-framework-6

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Windows Form, com Entity Framework 6 + MySQL.

Como é comum em sistemas, possuo em cada form botões de navegação (Primeiro Registro, Registro Anterior, Próximo Registro, Último Registro)

A dúvida: existe alguma sintaxe definida (LINQ ou Lambda), que me leve diretamente para o registro anterior ou próximo EXISTENTE?

Exemplo:
Estou com o form exibindo o registro ID = 6. Se eu clicar no botão anterior, devo  exibir o registro 5. Da mesma forma, o próximo é o registro 7. Porém, se o registro 7 não existir, deve ser exibido o registro 8.

Posso resolver facilmente com lógica de programação, porém gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira nativa da linguagem para resolver este tipo de operação.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você irá usar essa função logo após gravar o registro, ou poderá "navegar" por outras ações antes?

Comment: @Randrade, vou utilizar para navegar entre as opções, por exemplo ir par ao próximo registro, e retornar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A maneira mais elegante que conheço é usada para criar paginação em aplicações ASP.NET MVC, usando `Skip()` e `Take()`:

```
var registroAtual = 6;
var registroAnterior = contexto.Entidade.Skip(registroAtual - 2).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
var proximoRegistro = contexto.Entidade.Skip(registroAtual).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

**EDIT**

Supondo que eu queira especificamente achar os registros anterior e próximo ao Id 6:

```
var registroAnterior = contexto.Entidade.Where(e => e.Id <= 6).OrderByDescending(e => e.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
var proximoRegistro = contexto.Entidade.Where(e => e.Id >= 6).OrderBy(e => e.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Comment: Acho que não funciona para a pergunta... não podemos ter certeza que há 5 registros antes do registro só porque o ID é 6. Um ou mais (ou todos) os registros podem ter sido removidos.

Comment: @RSinohara Você possivelmente não entendeu o código. `Skip` não olha Id algum. Ele simplesmente pula X registros. `Take` pega os X primeiros registros depois de `Skip` e devolve uma lista, por mais que eu tenha feito `Take(1)`. Por fim, `FirstOrDefault()` pega o primeiro elemento da lista se houver, ou devolve `null` caso não haja um "próximo elemento". Teste e confira.

Comment: Sim, mas talvez haja só duas entradas antes da com ID 6, digamos com ID 3 e 5. Dar skip em 4 registros vai pular 3, 5, 6 e, digamos, 7, retornando o próximo ID. Não vai retornar a entrada anterior (no caso seria ID 5).

Comment: @RSinohara É, de fato você não entendeu. `Skip` e `Take` não olham Ids, nem ordem de Ids, e são os únicos que trabalham direito com `Guid`s. Eu poderia expandir a seleção fazendo `var proximoRegistro = contexto.Entidade.Where(e => e.Id == 6).Skip(registroAtual).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();`. Daria no mesmo.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez O seu código está correto, mas para paginação. O AP pediu para encontrar o Elemento anterior ao de ID 6. Pular 4 elementos não retorna o elemento anterior e seguinte ao de ID 6 (a não ser que todos os elementos estejam presentes com IDs de 1 até 5).  Rode mentalmente seu código para uma tabela só com os elementos com **IDs: 1, 5, 6, 1890, 1891, 5000, 12000 e 14000**. Ele vai retornar: `registroAnterior` com ID 1891 e `proximoregistro` com ID 12000.

Comment: @RSinohara Veja agora.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Acho que agora está pior: a clausula where retorna somente 1 item (considerando que existe). Skip nisso elimina o único item, zerando a coleção.

Comment: Talvez para usar skip teriamos que fazer `contexto.Entidade.OrderBy(e=>e.ID).Skip(contexto.Entidade.Where(e=>e.ID<registroAtual).Count()-1).FirstorDefault` mas dará erro se não houver entradas.

Comment: @RSinohara Deixa pra lá.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

Para o item anterior ao de ID 6:

```
Context.NomeEntidades.where(c=>c.ID<6).OrderByDescending(c=>c.ID).firstOrDefault();
```

E para o seguinte:

```
Context.NomeEntidades.where(c=>c.ID>6).OrderBy(c=>c.ID).firstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Obrigado @RebecaAbrantes, isso já me ajuda muito!